# Linux | CQ 5.6 | Class Loader Issue

Tags: linux, aem, apache-felix, sling

Has anyone face issues on Linux with class loader or loading of properties file in CQ 5.6?

Here is what we are trying:

- We have config node that is "com.a.b.c.DataConfig"
- When we try to load this configuration on Linux, it gives Null Pointer Exception

We have the same code with same configuration deployed on Windows Box and it is working fine.

We want to know is this is the known issues, and we have any patch or hotfixes available to fix this.

We can provide more details if needed.

Comment: Could you give some more details? For starters: is this config node an OsgiConfig? What is the full stack trace of NPE?

Comment: False alarm, the issue was due to the bundle was corrupted and this was the first time we were trying to deploy the build on linux machine. Usually we have builds deployments on windows machines. We found bundle was corrupted later after posting this thread. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm, the issue was due to the bundle was corrupted and this was the first time we were trying to deploy the build on linux machine. Usually we have builds deployments on windows machines. We found bundle was corrupted later after posting this thread. Apologies